# Can not initialize an array in the copy constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

I have a class

```
class TTable
{
private:
    std::string tableName;
public:
    TRow rows[10]; //this other class TRow
    TTable(const TTable&);
    int countRows = 0;
};
```

And I implement the copy constructor

```
TTable::TTable(const TTable& table) : tableName(table.tableName), countRows(table.countRows), rows(table.rows) 
{
    cout << "Copy constructor for: " << table.GetName() << endl;
    tableName = table.GetName() + "(copy)";
    countRows = table.countRows;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        rows[i] = table.rows[i];
    }
}
```

But the compiler curses on this `rows(table.rows)`. How to initialize an array? With the variables everything goes, everything is good. Thank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since raw arrays aren't copyable this way, use `std::aray<TRow,10> rows;` instead:

```
class TTable
{
private:
    std::string tableName;
public:
    std::array<TRow,10> rows;
    TTable(const TTable&);
    int countRows = 0;
};

TTable::TTable(const TTable& table) 
: tableName(table.tableName + "(copy)")
, countRows(table.countRows)
, rows(table.rows)  {
    cout << "Copy constructor for: " << table.GetName() << endl;
}
```

Comment: An error in std :: array <TRow, 10> rows; Incomplete Incomplete Type

Comment: Use `#include <array>` and be sure that `TRow` is competely declared before using it.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I needed

Comment: @Xom9ik You can omit the explicit declaration and definition of that copy constructor completely BTW, if you don't need the debug output any more. The compiler will generate a working one automatically for you.

Comment: This answer is misleading. A plain array data member can be copied and even assigned fine. The std:array thing is a distraction.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, but not using `rows(table.rows)` in the member initialization list.

Answer (score 5):

Your code does double-duty: in addition to copying in the body of the constructor, it also copies in the initialization list.

You don't have to do that: keep items that can be copied by the initializer list on the list, and remove them from the body; remove other items from initializer list:

```
TTable::TTable(const TTable& table)
:   tableName(table.tableName + "(copy)")
,   countRows(table.countRows)
{
    cout << "Copy constructor for: " << table.GetName() << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        rows[i] = table.rows[i];
    }
}
```

Above, `tableName` and `countRows` are initialized using the list, while `rows` are initialized in with a loop in the body.